# Cygwin pacakge does not have include library

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, cygwin

I need to run some bash commands (like make). As recommended I installed Cygwin through https://www.cygwin.com/install.html. After trying to use make command I got following error as:

> utils.c:40:10: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
>
> > #include <sys/resource.h>

I searched a lot and as suggested by others there should be such file under include directory. However, I do not see such directory. Also searching to find resource.h file inside installed package is failed. I would be thankful if you could guide me in this regard. (the folders inside my installed Cygwin is as the below image)
[image]

Comment: It would typically be `usr/include/sys/resource.h`

Comment: Under the path you specified (usr/include) there is only one sub-folder named 'bash'. I looked into it but no resource.h. @MadScientist

Comment: Well, I suppose you need to install more packages then.  Unfortunately I don't use Windows; on GNU/Linux everything "just works".  Hopefully someone familiar with Cygwin will come by and tell you what you need to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `cygwin-devel` package in `Devel` category.